# How do I renew my Visa/apply for an OCI card?

Tags: usa, indian-citizens

I am a 20F living in India. I was born in USA and moved here when I was five. I came here on a 5 year Indian Visa that expired ten years ago. As I was a minor at the time, I was not aware of the consequences. How do I renew my Visa/apply for an OCI card?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the government of India website for OCI application - https://passport.gov.in/oci/welcome